# c++ classes - conflicting declaration error

Tags: c++, class, static

I just started learning classes in C++ and I get this error for the code below: `conflicting declaration 'std::string PizzaOrder::toppings_offered'`

Can someone explain what's wrong with my code here?

```
class PizzaOrder
{
public:
    //all the toppings that are offered, constant array of strings
    static string toppings_offered[5];
    static double topping_base_cost;
};

string PizzaOrder::toppings_offered = {"onions", "bell peppers", "olives", "spinach", "tomatoes"};
double PizzaOrder::topping_base_cost = 0.50;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot that `toppings_offered` is an array of strings, rather than a string:

```
string PizzaOrder::toppings_offered[5] = {"onions", ... };
//                                  ^
//                                  |
```

(BTW, I'd expect a pizza order to *order* toppings, not *offer* them. Could it be that your design still is a bit scrambled?)

Answer (score 0):

`string PizzaOrder::toppings_offered[5]`

instead of

`string PizzaOrder::toppings_offered`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the same type in the definition as you do in the declaration:

```
string PizzaOrder::toppings_offered[5] = { ... };
```

The type is `string[5]`, not `string`.

Answer (score -1):

You cant do it like it. You need to create an instance the class by calling

```
PizzaOrder myPizzaOrder = new PizzaOrder();
myPizzaOrder.topping_offered {"","",""};
```